# Is there anyway to downgrade Azure SQL Database from VCORE to DTU model

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am maintaining a mysqldbserver in an Azure subscription. 
Currently, I am using the V-core based pricing model and usage is pretty low 2-17%.

In that case, how can I downgrade my pricing model from the v-core to DTU based model?

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the following steps to change the tier from vCore Model to DTU model.

Make sure you make a click on the Overview section of the specific Azure SQL Database on the portal.

[image]

Now make a click on the current vCore tier (left panel).

[image]

Next make a click where it says "Looking for basic, standard, premium?".

[image]

Now select the Edition (Basic, Standard, Premium) and DTU amount you want to reserve. Finally make a click on the "Apply" button.

[image]

Comment: will this change connection string,?

Comment: No. This is transparent to your connection string. @Ananthakrishna